# Twitter Bootstrap with PLAY framework setting nav bar <li> elements to active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, playframework

Hi I have a navbar in my home.scala.html as follows-

```
<ul  class="nav nav-justified">
<li><a href="@routes.Application.apps()">@Messages("views.main.apps")</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">@Messages("views.main.activity")</a></li>
<li><a href="@routes.Application.devices()">@Messages("views.main.devices")</a></li>
<li><a href="#">@Messages("views.main.account")</a></li>
<li id="logout"><a href="#">@Messages("views.main.logout")</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to set active class on click as follows-

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.nav > li').click(function (e) {
        $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');                
        });            
        });
</script>
```

However on running the application only the li elements which have href="#" get set as active ,the other li elements remain inactive on click even though the page is redirected to the link of the  tag.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Edit:The structure of the main.scala.html is

```
    <html>
    <head></head><body>
            <ul  class="nav nav-justified">

              <li><a href="@routes.Application.apps()">@Messages("views.main.apps")</a></li>
            <li ><a href="">@Messages("views.main.activity")</a></li>
            <li><a href="@routes.Application.devices()">@Messages("views.main.devices")</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">@Messages("views.main.account")</a></li>
            <li id="logout"><a href="#">@Messages("views.main.logout")</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

          </nav>
            <div id="showsspData">
            @content
            </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

Then the apps.scala.html will be as-
@main("string to pass"){
//html content for page
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **[e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)** to prevent default action of the anchor and target `.click()` handler on the anchors instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.nav > li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Ohh no!! It didn't now the class is getting set as active but the ahref does not redirect to new page on click

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to do here? If you want to redirect users to another page then what's the point of highlight the `li` element?

Comment: So what I am trying to do is I have a main.scala.html which has the header ,navbar and footer and the content for each page will be in seperate scala.html pages